# avoid to use a final String variable

Tags: java, swing, variables, actionlistener, final

I have created this GUI for one my application.in the overriden method `actionPerformed` I have to insert `final` for the string `command` because this variable is used in a inner class. There is a way to avoid this issue?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    final String command = e.getActionCommand();

    if(command.equals("add"))
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // ... code skipped ... //
                ous.writeObject(command);
                // ... code skipped ... //
            }
        }).start();
    }

    else if(command.equals("remove"))
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // ... code skipped ... //
                ous.writeObject(command);
                // ... code skipped ... //
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

i tried to resolve the issue declaring

```
String command = null;
```

at the beginning of code.

Comment: What would be the issue? Having to type "final"? :) Could you elaborate?

Comment: Your code doesn't confirm [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You should not create a new `Thread` instance for what you are trying to do, but use a `SwingWorker` instead (or call your `emptyTextField` on the EDT). Further, reading the value of the text fields in your thread should also happen on the EDT. And finally, closing your streams should happen in a `finally` block

Comment: What issue does this cause for you? Simply having a String declared final isn't itself a "problem." Could you elaborate on why this isn't appropriate for you? (and, perhaps, shorten your example?)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a separate class that implements `Runnable`, pass the `String` in the constructor and use that object for your thread creation. Like:

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private String command;

    public ThreadTask(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void run {
       //
    }
}
```

It also makes the code more readable IMO.

Comment: Agree, even though I said this wasn't possible

Answer (score 1):

No, that's a feature in java. It's a limitation in its "closure" implementation. Closure variables need to be final.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need `command` in your inner classes: by the time you create an instance, you know for sure the value of `command`, so you can as well use the actual value.

Having said that, I'd extract the apparently-repeated code in a proper non-anonymous class, and pass it a proper `command`. That would also change the design enough so that you could stop worrying about `command` being final.